# svcutil error after upgrading projects from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.6.1

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I am working on upgrading my .NET solution from 3.5 to 4.6.1. For this I have used VS 2015 to do the changes and compilation is almost going through fine. However, one of the projects in my solution is failing with the below error while compiling --

> D:/build/toolchain\Win32\winsdk-6.1.6000\bin\svcutil.exe /serviceName:Sim.WebService.SimServer d:\build\SimServer\webservice\SviWebService.exe
>   .....
>    Could not load file or assembly 'file:///d:\build\SimServer\webservice\SviWebService.exe' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

I think this is because the SviWebService.exe is generated using .NET 4.6.1 and we are executing the svcutil on this exe from an earlier version of winsdk, which is 6.1.6000 as seen above. I wanted to verify this by using svcutil from a newer version of winsdk like 8.0 but cannot do this because of some external dependencies. But can some confirm if my guess is correct. Basically, is .NET 4.6.1 compatible with older version of winsdk like 6.1.600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is the case, and While I can't confirm this is the case, you should be able to test this yourself fairly easily - as you've installed Visual Studio 2015, I would expect to find the correct version in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\SvcUtil.exe

Try running that version to register your service - if it works then you'll know for sure that it's a compatibility issue.